# In how many maximum possible ways can 4 triangles and 4 circles intersect each other in a plane?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 4 triangles and 4 circles intersect each other in a plane.
Now i am new to permutations and combinations.

My workout....

I tried to do with basic addition and multiplication rule.

But then i could not and shifted to $nCr$..

From here we see that that circles intersect in 4C2 ways and Triangles in 4c3 ways.

A method from basic addition and multiplication principles is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean, what is the maximum number of points at which the four triangles and four circles can intersect? Or something else?

Comment: Yes yes...the word maxm should had been included

Comment: Of course they can intersect in infinitely many ways. You have to indicate which ways are considered equivalent. Are these "full" circles and triangles, or only their circumferences?

Comment: i dont think superposing them is good idea...

Comment: are you saying infinite intersections for superposing them.......i think circumferences will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that:

- Any two circles intersect in at most $2$ points.
- Any circle and triangle intersect in at most $6$ points. (Each side can cut the circle in $2$ points, and there are $3$ sides.)
- Any two triangles intersect in at most $6$ points. (Each side of the first triangle can intersect at most $2$ sides of the other, and there are $3$ sides.)

Since there are $\binom 42$ ways to choose two circles, $4 \cdot 4$ ways to choose a circle and a triangle, and $\binom 42$ ways to choose two triangles, this gives us an *upper bound* of $$2 \cdot \binom 42 + 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 + 6 \cdot \binom 42 = 144$$ intersection points.

But can we achieve this? We need to draw a picture where every two circles intersect in $2$ points, every circle and triangle intersect in $6$ points, every two triangles intersect in $6$ points, and all these points are distinct.

Something like the picture below will do, though in some cases you might have to zoom in quite closely to see that the points are distinct. (Or just say that if we need to, we can move the four circle a tiny bit up and down to get rid of any triple intersections we're worried about.)

[image: circle-triangle intersections]

Comment: thats a good picture....